# Are there any ski touring routes in the Austrian\Swiss Alps suitable for kids?

Tags: children, alpine-touring, alps

I would like to go for a week on skialp tour with kids (3 adults, 3 kids ~8 years old) this winter (end of December to January). I would like to go from hut to hut as some kids are too small to stay in a tent. We already have experience with ski touring, winter tent camping and high altitude mountaineering.

I'm unable to find any routes\hut descriptions. Only advertisements from mountaineering companies offering a week tour.

Comment: just to be sure, by skialp you mean ski touring?

Comment: Also please provide information on how old the kids are, on the experience level of adults and kids and a more precise time of the trip (conditions vary a lot).

Comment: @april rain yes, it's ski touring

Comment: @imsodin the kids are 8 y.o. We are planning to go in 2-4 weeks. About adult experiance: I don't know how to measure, we go skialp with a tent in winter and we have experiance climbing mountains over 7000m. Kids phisically strong, has experiance climbing mountains and they are good in skiing. But they don't have much skialp experiance.

Comment: At least in Tirol region of Austria there still is not a lot of ski tour routes you can do because of snow conditions. It hasn't snowed much in autumn, and even though there were a few recent snow falls, snow cover is fairly inconsistent. Even in high mountains snow has been blown away in many places. So I don't think there will be any week long tours you can do, unless it snows quite a bit within the next 2-4 weeks. Even one day tour possibilities might be very limited. Do check avalanche reports before you go: http://www.lawine.at/